# Globals Declaration

Tags: python, global-variables

Is there a reason why, in Python, I have to type:

```
global x
x = "Hello World!"
```

instead of:

```
global x = "Hello World!"
```

Other than the fact that I'll get an error?

Comment: Because that's how the syntax is defined?

Comment: If you find an answer useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to declare `global x` in the function where you want to modify that global variable.

This lets python know that the variable `x` is not defined in the scope of the function, but in the `global` scope.

So, you would do the following:

```py
x = 1

def f(): # you need global, since you are modifying the value
    global x
    x += 1

def g(): # no need for global, since no modification
    print(x)

f()
g()
```